# Android Facebook Key Hashes Configuration

Tags: android, android-facebook

I m getting Error "This app ha no key hashes configured."

where i have configured key hashes as shown in below image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZwY5.png)

plz guide me, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For every machine, the hash key may be different. You need to include new fresh key.

To get the `hash key` , use the following code

```
 try {
        PackageInfo info =     getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR PACKAGE NAME",     PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String sign=Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);

        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanx Dinesh for quick reply.

Comment: Have you change your new hash key in Facebook developer console

Comment: Yes Dinesh, changed Hash Key in Facebook Developer Console, the problem was as it was, the issue resolved by reinstalling app, So now issue is resolved, thanx once again for your help & guidance.